# How can I use the cat function to output elements that fits within a constraint?

Tags: r, statistics

This is all done in RStudio. I was given a code that generates a 3 x 4 matrix.

```
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(12),3,4)
tmp
```

Resulting Matrix when running the code

```
> tmp
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.1607589 -0.2285195 -0.1870843  0.4137581
[2,]  1.7255603 -1.4128953  0.4516150 -0.2917940
[3,] -1.1189774  0.1093109  0.4306788 -1.8357013
```

I now have to use the cat function to extract the elements in the second row whose value is less than 0.2.

This is what I wrote:

```
Second_Row_Value_Check <- cat(tmp[2,] < 0.2)
Element_Output <- c()
for (i in Second_Row_Value_Check) {
  if(Second_Row_Value_Check [i] == TRUE)
    Element_Output <- c (Element_Output, tmp[2,i])
  
  else if(Second_Row_Value_Check [i] == FALSE)
    next
  
}

Element_Output
```

When I initially did it, I just used the cat function and all it came out was TRUE and FALSE statements, not the values themselves. So I thought of making a loop to go through each iteration of the statement and if a statement is TRUE, then I'd append that respected value into the Element_Output vector. If it's FALSE, I move on to the next iteration.

However, when I run the code this is what I get in the consol.

```
> Second_Row_Value_Check <- cat(tmp[2,] < 0.2)
FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE> Element_Output <- c()
> for (i in Second_Row_Value_Check) {
+   if(Second_Row_Value_Check [i] == TRUE)
+     Element_Output <- c (Element_Output, tmp[2,i])
+   
+   else if(Second_Row_Value_Check [i] == FALSE)
+     next
+   
+ }
> 
> Element_Output
NULL
```

I want Element_Output to show -1.4128953 and -0.2917940. What went wrong with my code and can fix it?

Comment: No need to get too complicated: `tmp[2,][tmp[2,] < 0.2]`

Comment: A slight reduction: `tmp[2, tmp[2,] < 0.2]`